# How to add sub-menu in My Account WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to ask some help.

```
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'misha_one_more_link' );
function misha_one_more_link( $menu_links ){
 
    // we will hook "anyuniquetext123" later
    $new = array( 'anyuniquetext123' => 'Gift for you' );
 
    // or in case you need 2 links
    // $new = array( 'link1' => 'Link 1', 'link2' => 'Link 2' );
 
    // array_slice() is good when you want to add an element between the other ones
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 1, true ) 
    + $new 
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 1, NULL, true );
 
 
    return $menu_links;
 
 
}
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_endpoint_url', 'misha_hook_endpoint', 10, 4 );
function misha_hook_endpoint( $url, $endpoint, $value, $permalink ){
 
    if( $endpoint === 'anyuniquetext123' ) {
 
        // ok, here is the place for your custom URL, it could be external
        $url = site_url();
 
    }
    return $url;
 
}
```

I am using this code to add custom menu on My Account page of WooCommerce:

This worked pretty well but it only adds menu link. I would like to add submenus under Gift for You for example is "For Her" or "For Him".

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is to override the file `plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php` and do whatever you want inside ;)